# Use variable as Global variable in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I need to use datosusuario variable in another file how can I do this?

My main.dart is a Login I need use the query result variable to print that result in my homepage Widget

Main.dart

```
class LoginStates extends State<Login>{

@override

Widget build(BuildContext context) {

TextEditingController user=new TextEditingController();

TextEditingController pass=new TextEditingController();

Future<List> _login() async{

  final response =await 

http.post("https://exclinico.com/admin/FlutterClases/login.php", body: {

 "correo": user.text,

 "password": pass.text,

});

print(response.body);

var datosusuario = json.decode(response.body);


 if (datosusuario.length==0) {
  //print("$nombre");
   }
   else{
     //print("$nombre");
   }
}
```

I need to use `datosusuario` variable in the drawer info.

Home.dart

```
 return new Scaffold(
  appBar: new AppBar(
    centerTitle: true,
    title: new Image.asset("assets/LOGO.png"),
    backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
  ),
  drawer: new Drawer(
    child: new ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        new UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
            accountName: new Text("Eduardo"),
            accountEmail: new Text("eduardo.hernandez@Utacapñulco.edu.mx"),
        currentAccountPicture: new CircleAvatar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          child: new Text("E"),
        ),),
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wonderful, you just discovered a fundamental computer science problem: state management!

There are a lot of ways to do state management in Flutter and I really recommend you **check out the [Flutter state management talk at this year's Google I/O](https://youtu.be/d_m5csmrf7I)**, where they outline the pros and cons of the different ways of handling state in Flutter.

Just for the sake of it, here's *one possible way* of doing it pragmatically:
You could just add the `datosusuario` as a constructor parameter to your `Home` widget, like so:

```dart
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  Home({
    @required this.datasusuario,
  });

  final datasusuario;

  @override
  Widget build() {
    // here you can use the datasusuario
  }
}
```

and then pass it to the `Home` widget from the `Login` widget:

```dart
Home(datasusuario: datasusuario),
```

Answer (score 7):

An alternative way to create a global that I prefer to use is to create a Provider/Service for this.

For example, say you want your variable importable and available in any file without instantiating an object, you can create a class with a static value like so:

**Service/Provider**

```
class GlobalData {
  static const var datosusuario = datosusuario_value;
}
```

**Use in another file**

```
import 'package:my_app_name/path/to/provider.dart' as Globals;

Globals.datosusuario;
```

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 ways, first you can pass the variable to the `home.dart` file using its constructor.

In your `home.dart` file,

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  final datosusuario;

  Home(this.datosusuario);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...
  }
}
```

In your `main.dart` file, use

```
Home(datosusuario)
```

---

Second solution: You can make the variable global to the `main.dart` file and import this file in `home.dart` and use it, but make sure it is not null.

```
var datosusuario; // in top of the main.dart
```